# How do I rename a NiFi attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow with a number of processes.
At a certain stage in the flow, a file has been read and some attributes have been added to the flowfile. The existing processes are legacy and so I cannot change the original name of the attribute in the legacy process. And the process may be used elsewhere.

So downstream, I now want to rename attribute 'A' to 'B' using a process configured at the NiFi GUI.

How do I rename an Attribute?

I can use UpdateAttribute and create a new property b and set its value to ${A}. But how do I delete property/attribute A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UpdateAttribute includes a "Delete Attributes Expression" property that can delete an attribute.

You can use 1 UpdateAttribute processor to create a new Attribute called B with the value of A, then add A to the "Delete Attributes Expression". It will do the Update and then the Delete - so it effectively renames the attribute.

[See the docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html)

> "The third way is the "Delete Attributes Expression"; this allows you
> to provide a regular expression and any attributes with a matching
> name will be deleted.
>
> Please note that "Delete Attributes Expression" supersedes any updates
> that occur. If an existing attribute matches the "Delete Attributes
> Expression", it will be removed whether it was updated or not. That
> said, the "Delete Attributes Expression" only applies to attributes
> that exist in the input FlowFile, if it is added by this processor,
> the "Delete Attributes Expression" will not detect it."

Comment: Many thanks @Sdairs. That functionality was staring me in the face and I didn't notice it.